# How to match two selections with Regular Expressions, when first selection is within the second selection

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get part of my Reg Exp (pcre flavor) working.

Here's the HTML structure. I want to select both ChildA and ChildB. (ie Match1: From Parent to ChildA; and Match2: From Parent to ChildB).

```
<Parent>
            <ChildA>..</ChildA>
            <ChildB>..</ChildB>
```

I tried

```
/<parent>(.|\n)*?<child(a|b)>/gmi
```

I tried with and without the question mark. It selects either up to ChildA or ChildB but not both.

Can anyone guide me please?

[Here's a fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/eL2sO6/1)

Below are the matches I'm trying to get (clarifying as requested by Petr Srníček):

Match 1:

```
<Parent>
            <ChildA>
```

Match 2:

```
<Parent>
            <ChildA>..</ChildA>
            <ChildB>
```

Comment: why you want to use regex?

Comment: In what language are you doing using regexes? In Perl you could use //g

Comment: I don't understand what you're expecting...

Comment: The question seems unclear, can you edit it to show the exact matches you want to get?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Your regex will never match the input - the case is wrong and you haven't used the case insensitive flag

Comment: @Bohemian you can look at the OP's fiddle to see the flags used.

Comment: Since your edit, I think what you're asking for is impossible. Your match2 does not exist in the original text, so can't be matched.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll clarify my question with your questions.

Avinash – I'm not aware of another way to select text by matching a pattern other than RegExp. Do let me know if there is another way.

Alex – I'm using Sublime Text but happy even if it works Fiddle link in my post. It's for a manual cleanup, not built into anything specific. I've included /g but didn't return the result I want.

Petr – I've added the matches I want as requested.

Bohemian – the /i for is set in the tool, so I hadn't added in my post but it's in the Fiddle link. Now added to my my post too.

Comment: @Chris Lear – This is awesome! Exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you Chris, you're a star!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do what you need:

```
/(<parent>.*?<child[ab]>).*?<child[ab]>/gmis
```

Note, I've added the `s` modifier and changed from `(a|b)` to `[ab]` to avoid unnecessary capturing groups.

See https://regex101.com/r/eL2sO6/2

Also note that match1 is as you requested. Your match2 will be the whole match. Add brackets round everything if you explicitly want it to be a submatch.